# Do I need to divide p-value by 2 if alternative has been coded as upper 1 tail test in scs.ttest_ind()?

Tags: python, p-value

The following was coded `scs.ttest_ind()` in python.

Hypothesis: mean of A is greater than mean of B.

```
tstat, pval = scs.ttest_ind(array_A, array_B, equal_var = False, alternative = 'greater')
```

The output of the code is as follows:

```
t-stat 0.5823
p-value 0.416
```

Answer (score 0):

No, by selecting a 1 tail the test is calculated, considering it.

Comment: Based on the output, would I be right to interpret that we cannot reject the null hypothesis (i.e. array_a = array_b) at 5% significance level?